# Copying cv::Mat to a vx_image

Tags: c++, opencv, openvx

I'm looking at optimising some code with NVidia's OpenVX, and from previous experience with the CUDA API, GPU memory allocation is always a significant overhead.

So, I have a series of cv::Mat from video that I want to copy into an image; the naive code is of course:

```
vxImage = nvx_cv::createVXImageFromCVMat(context, cvMat);
```

The optimisation would be to allocate a single image, then just copy the bits on top. Looking at the header files (documentation is rather scant) I find:

```
nvx_cv::copyCVMatToVXMatrix(vxImage, cvMat);
```

However, the name is `VXMatrix`, so the compiler complains about a mismatch between the `vx_matrix` and `vx_image` types, of course. As far as I can tell, there is no `copyCVMatToVXImage` API; am I missing something, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can find something in the [OpenCV - OpenVX samples](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/3.4.1/samples/openvx).

Comment: Turns out that `nvx_cv::createVXImageFromCVMat()` avoids memory copies, so there's no allocation to try to optimise away! Thanks for the samples, anyway.